# Telegram bot authentification

Tags: authentication, telegram-bot

A web service that contains all the methods for processing data is stored by Azure. In this case, only my telegram can process this data. Other applications are not allowed. But there is a possibility of expanding the service.

How do I know that the service is used by my telegram bot?

How to authenticate the application.

Well, I tried to use OAuth2.0, but i think it is not correct, because user is already authentificated with telegram, when he use telegram bot. My idea was to send a link to google auththentification in the beginning of bot job. By th way, ok, we know user`s data. May be I can check: Id, login etc. But some hacker can substitute this id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **How can I make sure that Webhook requests are coming from Telegram?**
>  If
>   you‘d like to make sure that the Webhook request comes from Telegram,
>   we recommend using a secret path in the URL you give us, e.g.
>   www.example.com/your_token. Since nobody else knows your bot’s token,
>   you can be pretty sure it's us.

[Telegram Bot FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#how-can-i-make-sure-that-webhook-requests-are-coming-from-telegr)

Comment: well, thats pretty nice